# Learning "register": are there any register-conflicts in this sentence

Tags: register

This text was written by [coffee1054](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13752) in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/please-show-me-my-mistakes):

> We gonna show that there is no contradiction with Ohm's law.

Is there any register-conflict in this sentence?

Moved into the body of the question after the title was edited by another member:

Is it prudent for non-native speakers who wish to write formal English to learn English by listening to or reading dialogue?

Comment: I believe that it's fine, as long as the learner knows what they are doing. Reading what and listening to what are also important, I'd say. (By the way, I only make a comment about the title, not any other parts.)

Comment: ... That's a really heavy disconnect between your title and question content; please edit so we know which question to answer. Also, please source your quotation.

Comment: I've edited the title of the question. The question comes from a paragraph submitted to this site by someone seeking grammatical advice, which is being treated as a proofreading request. I'm creating questions based on it in the hope the answers will be of help to him and be relevant for other visitors to the site.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks, but can you include a link to that question? And your amended title still asks a very different question than the content body does: "how should I learn" versus "is there any register conflict". The title question is off topic (opinion based) but the body question is not.

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name. We have different definitions of relevant.

Comment: @TRomano Including the sources of your quotations is *always* relevant. You didn't write that content, and by using it without attribution, you're breaking the site's TOS. Letting us view the original also provides a lot more context.

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name: Can you show me the TOS language where it is a violation for one to create a series of questions "based on" a question asked here?  Are you suggesting that questions asked here are not covered by the "Fair Use" doctrine?  Your attribution is not technically correct, BTW. My question is a paraphrase, not a quotation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19470/discussion-between-esoteric-screen-name-and-tromano).

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name: If you're going to edit the question, please try to spell correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say: "**No**, it's not at all prudent!" The body of your question is a relevant counter-example: it is just not at all appropriate for formal written English, despite being something you may hear in natural dialogue.

If you want to learn formal written English, then make sure you spend plenty of time studying formal written English.